# Advanced Search - Need ideas

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I use c# MVC(LINQ) to build some system,
I need to search data from one of the tables,
The table contains millions of rows, and in each search I get back thousands results, to prevent this I "take"(LINQ) only 100 every time and "skip"(LINQ) the number of page * 100.
I also allow to order(orderBy - LINQ) the results by the table rows(so the skip and take affected by this).

At the moment for simple search I wrote 10 function for 10 columns, and in every function I  wrote a lot of code so it work properly with the "order by"(10 columns).

Now I need to allow  Advanced Search(search on more than one column) and I have no idea of how to do so,
I'm sure that there is better way for do what I want.

I only need an idea of how to do advanced search using LINQ without actually write the SQL query.

Comment: You should try DynamicLinq

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/231706/Dynamic-query-with-Linq

Comment: Thank you, This is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I use http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net to do this.